# Как вытащить из JSON файла одно конкретное значение для доп. обработки в компоненте Angular 2 / 8?

Tags: json, angular2

Есть json файл с таким содержимым:

```html
{
  "pagesList":
  [
      {
        "pageUrl": "index",
        "imgUrl": "glavnaya",
        "imgNumber": 17
      },
      {
        "pageUrl": "second",
        "imgUrl": "secondimg",
        "imgNumber": 10
      }      
  ]
}
```

Для дальнейшей обработки в коде компонента мне нужно получить число 17 (из строки "imgNumber": 17) в виде переменной. При этом выводить это значение в шаблон не требуется. 
Вытаскиваю данные из json с помощью сервиса `img-carusel.service.ts` :

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImgCaruselService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPagesJson() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/from-server/pages.json');
  }

}
```

Далее в компоненте преобразую json в массив объектов Pages :
`testzone.component.ts`

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImgCaruselService } from '../img-carusel.service';
import {Pages} from '../pages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testzone',
  templateUrl: './testzone.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testzone.component.css'],
  providers: [ImgCaruselService]  
})
export class TestzoneComponent implements OnInit {

  pageParams:Pages [] = [];
  imgnum:number;

  constructor(private imgcaruselService: ImgCaruselService) {   
  }

  ngOnInit() {   
    this.imgcaruselService.getPagesJson().subscribe(data => this.pageParams=data["pagesList"]);    
  }
  
  //this.imgnum=this.pageParams[0]["imgNumber"];
}
```

`pages.ts`

```html
export class Pages {
    pageUrl: string;
    imgUrl:string;
    imgNumber: number;
}
```

Шаблон `testzone.component.html`:

```html
pageParams = {{pageParams|json}}

pageParams[0].imgUrl = {{pageParams[0]?.imgUrl}}

<ul *ngFor="let item of pageParams">
  <li>imgUrl = {{item?.imgUrl}}</li>
  <li>pageUrl = {{item?.pageUrl}}</li>
  <li>imgNumber = {{item?.imgNumber}}</li>
</ul>
```

На экране выводится следующее:

```html
pageParam = [ { "pageUrl": "index", "imgUrl": "glavnaya", "imgNumber": 17 }, { "pageUrl": "rafting", "imgUrl": "rafting", "imgNumber": 10 } ]
pageParam2 = glavnaya

    imgUrl = glavnaya
    pageUrl = index
    imgNumber = 17

    imgUrl = rafting
    pageUrl = rafting
    imgNumber = 10
```

Т.е. в шаблоне могу выводить любые значения из json файла, все ок.
Теперь пробую в компоненте присвоить переменной `imgnum` нужное мне значение из массива объектов `imgnum=this.pageParams[0]["imgNumber"];`. При перезагрузке страницы в браузере выводится пустой экран.

Как получить доступ к конкретным данным из json в коде компонента?
Спасибо.

Comment: А можно посмотреть код присвоения? В каком месте это происходит?

Comment: @SergeyRogachev, например такой код, который будет в компоненте `testzone.component.ts` - `this.imgnum=this.pageParams[0]["imgNumber"]; this.param = this.imgnum * 5;` и далее переменную `param` вывожу в шаблоне `testzone.component.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, Вы хотели сделать так:

```
ngOnInit() {   
    this.imgcaruselService.getPagesJson().subscribe(data => {
        this.pageParams=data["pagesList"];
        this.imgnum=this.pageParams[0]["imgNumber"];
        this.param = this.imgnum * 5;
    });    
}
```

Как только вы получите ответ, Вы сможете проинициализировать данные и они обновятся на форме